# How to use Eventbus in a widget?

Tags: android, widget, greenrobot-eventbus, appwidgetprovider

I'm trying to figure out how I can use the Greenbot Eventbus library in my AppWidgetProvider. I've tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
public class SimpleWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    RemoteViews remoteViews;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_widget);
            //set image
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.piggy_bank, R.drawable.piggy_bank);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            //set refresh button
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh_btn, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    //set total price
    @Subscribe
    public void onPriceEvent(TotalPriceEvent event) {
        double price = event.totalPrice;
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.total_amount, String.valueOf(price));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onDisabled(context);
    }
}
```

Please, let me know if I need to attach more code.

Answer (score 3):

An `AppWidgetProvider` is just a `BroadcastReceiver` with a specialized `onReceive()` method that delegates broadcasts to other methods based on the action. Instances of a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` aren't meant to live very long. They run just long enough to handle a broadcast and then die, so subscribing one to an event bus isn't going to work as expected, and is kinda pointless, given the overlapping patterns. If you want to notify your `SimpleWidgetProvider` of something, just send a broadcast to it.

For an example, we define our own action for the `SimpleWidgetProvider` class, and check for it in the `onReceive()` method. If it's ours, we'll handle it as needed, and otherwise call the `super` method to allow `AppWidgetProvider` to properly delegate it.

```
public class SimpleWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static final String MY_SPECIAL_ACTION = "com.mycompany.myapp.SPECIAL_ACTION";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(MY_SPECIAL_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // Do your thing
        }
        else {
            // Not our action, so let AppWidgetProvider handle it
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

We can send a broadcast to it with the usual mechanism.

```
Intent widgetNotify = new Intent(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
widgetNotify.setAction(SimpleWidgetProvider.MY_SPECIAL_ACTION);
widgetNotify.putExtra(...);
...
context.sendBroadcast(widgetNotify);
```

---

I would also mention that the `super` calls in `onEnabled()` and `onDisabled()` are unnecessary, as those methods are empty in `AppWidgetProvider`.

Comment: Wherever you would've posted your `TotalPriceEvent` to the `EventBus`.